# How to fix some views in Relative Layout

Tags: android, layout

I have implemented simple relative layout for chat inside one of fragments layout called "Chat". The problem is that when I click EditText to type message, Linear Layout for sending messages disappears and messages are superimposed on the items above(I want them no to overlay any element except recycler view).
How to fix it?
Below I put the code of layout and screenshots [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wItb.png) and [Layout after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76h5j.png)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChatFragment">

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/start_at_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Start at"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/attachBtn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_file"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="Start typing..."
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_chat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/chat_layout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="#AEFFFFFF"
            tools:listitem="@layout/message_left" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if you're following a tutorial or just developing yourself, consider improving your layouts by just using constraint layout, having relative, linear and constraint in one is overkill and worse for performance

Comment: well I am using Relative Layout to place toolbar and bottom view

Comment: so is it possible to fix it in my case?